# MySQL: Deleting single selected row in a limited range

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I am attempting to delete a single row in a `LIMIT` range. Is this correct? If not, how can I correctly express the following query?

```
DELETE (
    SELECT * FROM `table_name`
    WHERE column_1 = 101
    ORDER BY column_2 ASC
    LIMIT 0, 1
    )
```

EDIT:
Let's say I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE column_1 = 101 ORDER BY column_2 ASC
```

And that this query get's me 3 rows:

```
column_1   column_2   value
101        1          x
101        2          y
101        3          z
```

So `LIMIT n, 1` Will get me the 1 SINGLE row from n. So `LIMIT 0, 1` gets me the first row. `LIMIT 1, 1` gets me the second row. `LIMIT 2, 1` gets me the third row.

So let's say I want to `SELECT` only the third row:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE column_1 = 101 ORDER BY column_2 ASC LIMIT 2, 1
```

This works perfectly. Yet the following does not work:

```
DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE column_1 = 101 ORDER BY column_2 ASC LIMIT 2, 1
```

I get the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' 1' at line 1
```

Comment: To delete you can simply use  - DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE  id = (select id FROM `table_name` WHERE column_1 = 101 ORDER BY column_2 ASC LIMIT 2, 1).

By id, I mean the primary key of the table or some combination that is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't allow you to use the `LIMIT offset, row_count` syntax in `DELETE` queries, only `LIMIT row_count`.

So you'll need to join with a subquery to select the row you want.

```
DELETE t1
FROM table_name AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT id
    FROM table_name
    WHERE column_1 = 101
    ORDER BY column_2 ASC
    LIMIT 2, 1
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

The table needs to have a primary key column, replace `id` in the above query with the name of that column.

Comment: Incredible... It worked perfectly. Thank you, Barmar!

Answer (score 1):

Just do something like:

```
Delete FROM `table_name`
    WHERE column_1 = 101
    ORDER BY column_2 ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `LIMIT 2` should be `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @Barmar: I think the question is looking for a range within which the delete can be done.. If I only have limit 1, that would delete the first record it encounters. But in case I want to delete 10 records and I want to skip the 1st 10 records and want to delete the next 10, I encounter, I don't think this would work...

Comment: @user3115056 You can use `LIMIT 10, 1` to skip the first 10 and delete the next one. But the question uses `LIMIT 0, 1`, which means the first one encountered. He was just confused about how to specify the limit when deleting.